# How to create vertx router using Scala

Tags: scala, vert.x

I am trying to create vertx Router using Scala. The build file is shown beow:

```
name := "Myapp"
version := "0.1"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
libraryDependencies += "io.vertx" %% "vertx-lang- scala-stack" % "3.6.3" 
libraryDependencies += "io.vertx" %% "vertx-lang- scala" % "3.6.3"
```

The verticle is created as shown below:

```
import io.vertx.lang.scala.ScalaVerticle
import io.vertx.scala.ext.web.Router

class WebService extends ScalaVerticle {

override def start() {
    //start http server
    val server = vertx.createHttpServer()

    //create router

    val router = Router.router(vertx)
    var route = router.route().path("/")

    val route = router.get("/")
    route.handler(( 
context :io.vertx.scala.ext.web.RoutingContext ) 
=> {
        var response = context.response()
        response.putHeader("content-type", 
"text/plain")
        response.end("hello world")
    })

    println("web service started on 8080")
    server.listen(8080)
}

override def stop() {    }

}
```

sbt compile command generates errors as shown below  Error:

```
com/bca/WebService.scala:4:23: object ext is not 
a member of package io.vertx.scala
[error] import io.vertx.scala.ext.web.Router                      
[error]

 com/bca/WebService.scala:15:22: not found: value 
Router
[error]         val router = Router.router(vertx)
[error]                      ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) 
Compilation failed
```

I am looking at Router class [here](https://github.com/codepitbull/vertx-lang-scala-stack/blob/master/vertx-web-scala/src/main/scala/io/vertx/scala/ext/web/Router.scala). The router is defined in the package io.vertx.scala.ext.web. I am not sure why sbt is complaining that object ext is not a member of io.vetx.scala

I am not sure how to create a router and use it. A simple example would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sbt is complaining because `vertx-web-scala` dependency is missing. Please add it to your build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies += "io.vertx" %% "vertx-web-scala" % "3.6.3"
```

Your code contains more compilation issues, for instance `route` variable is defined twice.

I recommend starting with [the official Vertx blog](https://vertx.io/blog/scala-is-here/) or [Vertx Giter8 template](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-scala.g8). It will give you a fully working project in 1 minute.